# jQuery is not changing the next form on the page?

Tags: jquery

I've got the following HTML code:

```
<ul id="contributorPhotos">
    <li>
        <img src="viewIcon.png" class="View">
        <img src="editIcon.png" class="Edit">
        <img src="deleteIcon.png" class="Delete">
        <form>
            [Form fields to manage first image here]
        </form>
    </li>

    <li>
        <img src="viewIcon.png" class="View">
        <img src="editIcon.png" class="Edit">
        <img src="deleteIcon.png" class="Delete">
        <form>
            [Form fields to manage second image here]
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And my jQuery controlling this:

```
<script>
    $(".Edit").click(function() {
        $(this).find("form").css("background-color","#03C");
    });
</script>
```

As you can see, all I'm trying to do right now is change the background color of the form below the current edit button, but I'm hitting a wall.

Can someone explain why this isn't working?

Comment: .find is looking through descendants, so if you're binding it to a sibling element, it's not going to "find" the form as a descendant of that element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) only works on descendants of the element you select, and you're looking for a sibling.

Use this:

```
$(".Edit").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings("form").css("background-color","#03C");
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Cv8JD/)**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to say $(this).parent().find("form")

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $.document.ready( function() {
        $(".Edit").click(function() {
            $(this).find("form").css("background-color","#03C");
        });
    }
</script>
```

It's likely that your click function is never being bound to the click event.

Comment: Sorry... meant to say that the rest of the page is intact... there is a valid doctype, and this code is within a document.ready block.  I stripped down the code for the post.

Comment: OK, then I'd go with j08691 or Larry's answer

Answer (score 0):

ummmm I gotta say that a form tag isn't allowed in a list tag...

EDIT:

David Byers, not to annoy you but your html is wrong... Image tags aren't allowed in a list tag.. neither are form tags.. you should add a background image to ur 'buttons' with css... the html would look something like this:

```
<div class="contributorPhotos">
        <!-- give background image and with to ur list tags -->
    <ul>
        <li class="View">View</li>
        <li class="Edit">Edit</li>
        <li class="Delete">Delete</li>
    </ul>

    <form>
        [Form fields to manage first image here]
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use instead:

```
$(".Edit").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').find("form").css("background-color","#03C");
});
```

The problem you're facing is the way that `find()` works: it looks within the current element (in this case the `$('.Edit')` element, which is an image, for the element(s) defined by the selector within the `find`. As an image can't contain any other elements this could never work. The alternative, above, moves to the parent `li` element and then searches within *that* element for the `form`.

You could also try using:

```
$(".Edit").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings("form").css("background-color","#03C");
});
```

Which will search among the sibling elements of the `$('.Edit')` element.

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).